# Netty how to resolve dns on socks proxy?

Tags: java, netty, socks

How to resolve host name remote when i use SocksProxy ?
As i can see `Socks5ProxyHandler` (4 ty) allow this.

```java
if (raddr.isUnresolved()) {
    addrType = Socks5AddressType.DOMAIN;
    rhost = raddr.getHostString();
} else {
...
}
```

But netty always resolve dns on call `connect()`. Is there currently a way to resolve the host name remotely ?

It's about using Socks5(4)ProxyHandler as your first handler. For proxying traffic.

And i found similar issue on netty github - https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7487

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7487

```java
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.resolver(NoopAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
```

this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.resolver(NoopAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
```

is OK.